# What is the best way to secure a webservice?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, web-services

As the title allready explains I want to secure my webservice.
I've read that you can do this using an soap authentication header, but then the username en password are passed as plain text.

I was wondering what I should do to secure my webservice?
Examples would be great.

I have an example of a company we work with that has 2 webservices.
One to do the security and one to get the needed data but I don't have their side of the code the system looks great though:

```
bool loginSuccessFull = false;

/// knooppunt
string loginID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceLogin"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServicePass"];


//A. The m_SecurityService object is created and initialised
Security securityService = new Security();
securityService.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();


string challenge = securityService.InitializeLogin(loginID);
string pwd = password;
string response = pwd + challenge;


System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
SHA1.Initialize();
byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(response));

System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in hash)
    builder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

//2. A login is done with the m_SecurityService object
if (securityService.Login(builder.ToString()))
{
    string ssoToken = Request.QueryString["SSOTOKEN"];
    string ssoID = Request.QueryString["SSOID"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ssoToken) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ssoID))
    {
        // Check with webserice if the token is valid.
        Knooppunt.SSO.GenericSSO sso = new Knooppunt.SSO.GenericSSO();
        sso.CookieContainer = securityService.CookieContainer;
        try
        {
            if (sso.validateSSOToken(Convert.ToInt32(ssoID), ssoToken))
            {
                loginSuccessFull = true;
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("default user", false);
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it truly is a webservice, you should be using [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) to generate the proxy and make the call.  It makes a lot of this code much, much easier.

Honestly, it looks like the package that is used to connect to the web service that you are using (SSO?) is pretty non-standard, and does nothing more than derive from [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), which is VERY low-level, and too complex to use.

If you are going to secure your own web service (and you are exposing it over an HTTP channel), the easiest way is to get a digital certificate for your host and then use basic HTTP authentication over HTTPS.

You could also use other aspects of the [WS-Security specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) (e.g. encoding the message, etc, etc) to secure your service.

Note that WCF supports **all** of these options, so you don't have to do any of this coding out of the box, and you can host it in IIS as well.

A good beginners reference to WCF is [Michelle Bustamante's "Learning WCF: A Hands-On Guide"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627).

After that, for more advanced WCF content (especially if you want to learn about concepts revolving around security in WCF and WS-* in general) I *highly* recommend ["Programming WCF Services" by Juval Lowy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308).

Comment: Totally agreed.  No need to re-invent the wheel. WCF is for exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @Sem Dendonker: Can you use .NET 3.0?  WCF is in .NET 3.0, and that was a pure add-on solution (only libraries were added, no changes to base class libraries or the CLR), so it should be painless if you are using .NET 2.0.

Comment: My WS will be accessed from AS400 server. In such case would WCF will work?